# Error when i hide ID field in Edit page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a regular data list page where my data are from an SQL database

when i enter the regular "Edit" page to change the name and other things of a record, i tried to hide the ID field because i don't want the user to see the ID or to modify it and i got the following error: dbupdateconcurrencyexception!!! and it shows on the:

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

if i put the ID field back to normal (where the user can change it) it works fine !!!

so how can i hide or make the ID field readonly without having this error !!!

the system by default used:

```
        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Identifier)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Identifier)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Identifier)
    </div>
```

so to be able to make it as a ready only i used:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Identifier, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Comment: How are you hiding the id-field, in a HiddenFor(x=>x.id) ?

Comment: How are you hiding the ID? are you using Html.HiddenFor?

Comment: please, show your cshtml markup

Comment: _"so how can i hide or make the ID field readonly without having this error !!!"_ - that is not how HTTP and security work. You need to verify that the client posting an entity has the proper permissions to modify the entity identified by the posted ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want post something to controller, you need fill it by value. If you don't want to show it to user, write this:

`@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Identifier;`

Disable TextBox doesn't send data also, so you need to write hidden too.